# Finding a mapping to permutate a list

Tags: matrices, permutations, combinations

Let 
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
   a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
   a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
   a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
\end {bmatrix},
$$
furthermore let $a$ be a vector which is built from $A$ by stacking its coloumns
$$
a = \begin {bmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{21} & a_{31} & a_{41} & a_{12} & a_{22} & a_{32} & a_{42} & a_{13} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{43} & a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} & a_{44}
\end {bmatrix}^{\text{T}}
$$
Now let $b$ another vector, whose elements are a specific permutation of $a$
$$
b = \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{22} & a_{32} & a_{23} & a_{33} & a_{42} & a_{12} & a_{43} & a_{13} & a_{24} & a_{34} & a_{21} & a_{31} & a_{44} & a_{14} & a_{41} & a_{11}
\end {bmatrix}^{\text{T}}
$$
This arrangement is motivated by dividing $A$ into blocks of $2\times 2$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11} & | & a_{12} & a_{13} & | & a_{14} \\
   - & - & - & - & - & -\\
   a_{21} & | & a_{22} & a_{23} & | & a_{24} \\
   a_{31} & | & a_{32} & a_{33} & | & a_{34} \\
   - & - & - & - & - & -\\
   a_{41} & | & a_{42} & a_{43} & | & a_{44}
\end {bmatrix},
$$
The "boundary" of the matrix is supposed to be periodic, so that the neighborhood of $a_{11}$ for example reads
$$
\begin {bmatrix}
   & a_{41} & \\
   a_{14} & a_{11} & a_{12} \\
   & a_{21} &
\end {bmatrix}\, .
$$
The vector $b$ is constructed by stacking the coloumns of the $2\times 2$ blocks, starting with the central block.

I'm looking for a mapping $M \in \mathbb R^{16 \times 16}$ such that $b = M a$. For the given example, $M$ turns out to be
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
    &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &  \\
    & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1\\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 &   &  \\
    &   &   & 1 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
   1&   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &  \\
\end {bmatrix}\, .
$$
Zero elements of $M$ are omitted. Now I was hoping to notice a pattern, so that $M$ could be generalized to permute vectors $a \in \mathbb R^{n^2}$ where $n$ is even, which are constructed coloumnwise from $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ in the same way.

However I'm unable to see a pattern in the matrix $M$, what am I missing? Is there a better way to represent this combination?

Comment: What is the permutation when $n$ is odd?

Comment: Ah I forgot to add, $n$ is supposed to be even, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python function that computes the new position (in vector $b$) of a matrix coefficient at position $k\in [0, n^2)$ in vector $a$,
and a function that computes the old position in vector $a$ of a matrix coefficient at position $k$ in vector $b$

```
def newpos(k, n):
    a, u = divmod(k, 2 * n)
    b, u = divmod(u, 4)
    c, d = divmod(u, 2)
    return n * ((2 * a + c + 1) % n) + ((2 * b + d + 1) % n)

def oldpos(k, n):
    u, v = divmod(k, n)
    if u == 0: u = n
    if v == 0: v = n
    a, c = divmod(u-1, 2)
    b, d = divmod(v-1, 2)
    return 2 * n * a + 4 * b + 2 * c + d
```

The `divmod` operator performs euclidean division, so `u, v = divmod(k, n)` means that
$$k = n u + v$$
with $0\le v\lt n$.